# Is memory fence and memory barrier same?

Tags: c++, rust, atomic, processor

here I am confused with the term memory fence (fence function in rust). I can clearly understand what is memory barrier in terms of atomics but I was unable to figure out what is memory fence.

Are memory fence and memory barriers the same? if not what is the difference and when to use memory fence over memory barrier?

Comment: Wiki says: "_A memory barrier, also known as a membar, memory fence or fence instruction, is a type of barrier instruction that causes a central processing unit (CPU) or compiler to enforce an ordering constraint on memory operations issued before and after the barrier instruction. This typically means that operations issued prior to the barrier are guaranteed to be performed before operations issued after the barrier._"

Comment: @TedLyngmo have you personally used a memory fence? I am asking this because while seeing some project which used memory fence looks somewhat different usecase than memory barrier, just my view.

Comment: I'm sure I have, many times. I mostly use things I need and explore what they have to offer when the need arises though. I'm not much for theory unfortunately

Comment: tnx @TedLyngmo for making this clear 

Comment: Why is this marked C++ and Rust? Do these two languages share the same memory model with regard to synchronization? When you say "memory fence", are you talking about the language definition of the term or the concept at the CPU level?

Comment: @NicolBolas i have tagged rust as it inherited memory model from c++ and also I tagged c++ because this concept not only depends on the processor but also involves compiler

Comment: @NicolBolas It's tagged that way because OP tries to figure things out on a user (programming) level.

Answer (score 11):

A "fence" in this context is a *kind* of memory barrier. This distinction is important. For the purposes of this discussion I'll distinguish informally between three kinds of beasts:

- Atomic fence: controls the order in which observers can see the effects of atomic memory operations. (This is what you asked about.)
- More general memory barrier: controls the order of actual operations against memory or memory-mapped I/O. This is often a bigger hammer that can achieve similar results to an atomic fence, but at higher cost. (Depends on the architecture.)
- Compiler fence: controls the order of instructions the processor *receives.* This is not what you asked about, but people often accidentally use this *in place* of a real barrier, which makes them sad later.

### What fence is

Rust's `std::sync::atomic::fence` provides an *atomic fence* operation, which provides synchronization between other atomic fences and atomic memory operations. The terms folks use for describing the various atomic conditions can be a little daunting at first, but they are pretty well defined in the docs, though at the time of this writing there are some omissions. Here are the docs I suggest reading if you want to learn more.

First, [Rust's docs for the `Ordering` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html). This is a pretty good description of how operations with different `Ordering` interact, with less jargon than a lot of references in this area (atomic memory orderings). However, at the time of this writing, it's misleading for your specific question, because it says things like

> This ordering is only applicable for operations that can perform a store.

which ignores the existence of `fence`.

The [docs for `fence`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/fn.fence.html) go  a little ways to repair that. IMO the docs in this area could use some love.

However, if you want all the interactions precisely laid out, I'm afraid you must look to a different source: [the equivalent C++ docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence). I know, we're not writing C++, but Rust inherits a lot of this behavior from LLVM, and LLVM tries to follow the C++ standard here. The C++ docs are *much* higher in jargon, but if you read slowly it's not actually more complex than the Rust docs -- just jargony. The nice thing about the C++ docs is that they discuss each interaction case between load/store/fence and load/store/fence.

### What fence is not

The most common place that I employ memory barriers is to reason about completion of writes to memory-mapped I/O in low level code, such as drivers. (This is because I tend to work low in the stack, so this may not apply to your case.) In this case, you are likely performing `volatile` memory accesses, and you want barriers that are *stronger* than what `fence` offers.

In particular, `fence` helps you reason about which atomic memory operations are visible to which other atomic memory operations -- it does *not* help you reason about whether a particular stored value has made it all the way through the memory hierarchy and onto a particular level of the bus. For instance. For cases like that, you need a different sort of memory barrier.

These are the sorts of barriers described in considerable detail in [the Linux Kernel's documentation on memory barriers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt).

In response to another answer on this question that flat stated that fence and barrier are equivalent, I [raised this case on the Rust Unsafe Code Guidelines issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/260) and got some clarifications.

In particular, you might notice that the docs for `Ordering` and `fence` make no mention of how they interact with `volatile` memory accesses, and that's because they *do not.* Or at least, they aren't guaranteed to -- on certain architectures the instructions that need to be generated are the same (ARM), and in other cases, they are not (PowerPC).

Rust currently provides a portable atomic fence (which you found), but does not provide portable versions of any other sort of memory barrier, like those provided in the Linux kernel. If you need to reason about the completion of (for example) `volatile` memory accesses, you will need either non-portable `asm!` or a function/macro that winds up producing it.

### Aside: compiler fences

When I make statements like what I said above, someone inevitably hops in with (GCC syntax)

```c
asm("" :::: memory);
```

This is neither an atomic fence *nor* a memory barrier: it is roughly equivalent to Rust's `compiler_fence`, in that it discourages the *compiler* from reordering memory accesses across that point in the generated code. It has no effect on the order that the instructions are started or finished by the machine.

Comment: Does this mean the when we use atomic ordering internally a fence is used?

Comment: @mslot, it depends on the target architecture, but in general, yes. If you use a higher-level abstraction like a store with "acquire" memory ordering, the appropriate fence instruction will be included if required. (on 32-bit ARM this is typically a `DSB` instruction, on 64-bit ARM there's a specific load-acquire instruction, and on x86 the situation is weird but usually no instruction is required.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

"Fence" and "barrier" mean the same thing in this context.

Comment: This is literally the answer folks

Comment: This is perhaps not the answer I'd click "useful" on although you usually deliver them :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's a direct and complete answer to a very simple question - what more is there to say 

Comment: :-) (old time 7 bit emoji) It's sometimes hard to figure out the diff between certain words in English. Reading about programming takes someone not fluent a lot longer. It takes me 3-6 times longer to read - and digest -  English publications than if I'd gotten them in Swedish.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Right, and the answer to this question is "there is no difference", which is what I said :(

Comment: Perhaps clarifying that in a way even future readers could appreciate is just the pill?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, I didn't understand you. Are you suggesting an improvement? What is it?

Comment: I have simplified the language even further, in case that's what you meant. But I think it was pretty clear for today and future readers alike

Comment: "Are you suggesting an improvement" - Yes, but perhaps because I've read your previous explanations. It's not mandatory :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's fine, but you're going to have to actually tell me what the suggested improvement is...

Comment: No, I don't have specific suggestions. I've even reverted my -1 and am educating myself until I'm confident in voting +1. :)

Comment: Is [this](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/fences-as-memory-barriers) close? Load/Store's galore. As you said, "the same thing **in this context**" seems like a fit.

Comment: I mean, in any context really a fence is just a kind of barrier. That's what the words mean, and we can see this in any dictionary