# Can I use atomic fences to ensure order of volatile_read and volatile_write?

Tags: rust, cpu, ipc, shared-memory, lock-free

I want to use shared memory between processes to send potentially large messages.

Writer process should:

1. Write a large block of data into the memory.
2. Then write a boolean to a defined address to signalise it's done.

Reader process should:

1. Read the defined address in a loop until it notices the signal.
2. Once the signal is received, read the large block of data from memory.

I wanted to implement write as:

1. `volatile_write` of the large block
2. release fence
3. assign to memory pointer casted as `AtomicBool` reference

I wanted to implement the read as:

1. read from memory pointer casted as `AtomicBool` reference
2. acquire fence
3. `volatile_read` of the large block

Several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596654/is-memory-fence-and-memory-barrier-same/65171678#65171678) and [discussions](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/260) seem to imply that fences have no effect on anything besides atomics. But that seems to contradict posts like [this](https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt).

Now I am confused. Would my approach work? If not, what is the right way?

Comment: You just need the atomic store to be a release operation, and the atomic load to be an acquire operation.  That will sync the reader to the writer if it sees `data_ready == true`, guaranteeing that you can see all earlier stores in the writer. (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/)  If the compiler implements that with fences, that's fine, but it could do it more cheaply on some ISAs like AArch64 with just `stlb` / `ldab`.

Comment: You probably don't need `volatile_write` either; a release operation will force the compiler to make earlier stores visible to something that could sync.  The discussion you linked on github was about ordering wrt. stores to MMIO, usually an uncacheable mapping, which might make asm memory fence instructions unnecessary on some ISAs.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for all the help. If you want to write that into the answer, I will gladly accept it.